# Tortoisesvn error passwd:6: Section header expected

Tags: tortoisesvn, sectionheader

Sorry for asking but I need to access a remote repository. I was given an account on the server side and i have installed tortoise svn on my client machine. the problem is i cant access, update or commit changes because i keep geting the above error. I think i have to make some changes in the .conf file but I do not know which changes to make exactly. thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `C:\repository\conf\passwd` which contains usernames and password for authentication. Take a closer look at the file, fix it and this should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.